# Beamer multi-language text alignment

Tags: beamer, polyglossia, hebrew, bidi

I encountered a weird issue with the `Polyglossia` package. RTL text is centred unless I insert before text in english.

MWE1 (Hebrew text is centred):

```
%Compile with XeLaTex
\documentclass{beamer}
%-----------------------
%:Language
%------------------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{FreeSans}
\begin{document}
%text
\frame{\frametitle{} טקסט}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I add a word in English before the text in Hebrew, Text is aligned to the right (as it should be). In the following example I have added the word "text" (line 13):

MWE1 (Hebrew text is centred):

```
%Compile with XeLaTex
\documentclass{beamer}
%-----------------------
%:Language
%------------------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{FreeSans}
\begin{document}
text
\frame{\frametitle{} טקסט}
\end{document}
```

[image]